# Google cloud engine disk is 100 GB but it says it's full at ~50GB

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to using google cloud engine. I'm having trouble understanding why my disk is supposed to be 100 GB but it's full when there's not much on it. I have now deleted that instance and created another that is also supposed to be 100 GB but again it's not. I'm sure there's an explanation but despite reading a great number of answers to similar questions here, I can't get this resolved. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? [Disclaimer: I'm new to using commands in a terminal etc.]

---

From VM instance details

Image: 
ubuntu-minimal-1604-xenial-v20191113

Size (GB):
100

---

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          41G   31G   10G  76% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           847M     0  847M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        41G   31G   10G  76% /root
/dev/sdb1       4.8G  4.6G     0 100% /home
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
overlayfs       1.0M  164K  860K  17% /etc/ssh/keys
overlayfs       1.0M  164K  860K  17% /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
tmpfs           847M  700K  846M   1% /run/metrics
tmpfs           847M     0  847M   0% /run/google/devshell
```

```
me@cloudshell:~ (first-try-at-project)$ lsblk

NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   45G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1      40.9G  0 part /var/lib/docker
├─sda2    8:2    0   16M  0 part
├─sda3    8:3    0    2G  0 part
├─sda4    8:4    0   16M  0 part
├─sda5    8:5    0    2G  0 part
├─sda6    8:6       512B  0 part
├─sda7    8:7    0  512B  0 part
├─sda8    8:8        16M  0 part
├─sda9    8:9    0  512B  0 part
├─sda10   8:10   0  512B  0 part
├─sda11   8:11        8M  0 part
└─sda12   8:12   0   32M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0    5G  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0    5G  0 part /home
zram0   252:0    0  768M  0 disk [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow just after finally posting my quetion I have figured this out!

I didn't realize before that:

> When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a g1-small Google Compute Engine virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating system.

What I needed to do was connect to the VM instance using SSH.

I hope my answer to my own question can help someone else who is new to this and struggling.

Comment: Saying it another way, when you ran the df command, you were running it on the Linux machine that corresponds to your cloud shell ... as opposed to running it on the Linux machine that is your Compute Engine instance.